# Shade a region of ggplot where x,y satisfy a constraint

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to generate a `ggplot` in which the entire region where X and Y satisfy the following constraint is shaded:

(XY) / (X+Y-1) > 2

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't think I could plot the *entire* region, but how about this: The inequality is equivalent to `y > 2*(x-1)/(x-2)`, so let's find the critical y value for each x and then plot the region where the inequality is satisfied:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = seq(-10,14,0.001)
y = 2*(x-1)/(x-2)
dat = data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin=y, ymax=ifelse(x>2, Inf,-Inf)), fill="blue") +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=range(-10,14), xlim=c(-10,14),expand=FALSE) +
  labs(y="y") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=2, colour="red", size=0.5, alpha=0.5)
```

The horizontal red line shows the critical value that y approaches (which is 2) as the absolute value of x gets large.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trying with ggplot2,dplyr.
Some data:

```
df<-data.frame(x=runif(1:100),y=runif(1:100))
```

Adding the constraint:

```
df1<-df%>%mutate(constraint=ifelse((x*y/(x+y-1))>2,"yes","no"))
```

constraints:

```
which(df1$constraint=="yes")->k
```

the plot:

```
ggplot()+geom_area(data=df1[k,],aes(x,y,fill=constraint),alpha=0.5)+geom_point(data=df1[k,],aes(x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: But the result doesn't really make sense -- some values of (x,y) are shaded in both colors, indicating both meeting and not meeting the constraint.

Comment: yup...agreed. The answer by @eipi10 is correct. The geom_area gives the area defined by the constraint =="yes". I made the edits. In any case I'd prefer geom_ribbon answer.